# How can I capture the generated message inside Check?

Tags: warning-messages, error-propagation

Consider the following toy function:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[str_, n_] := Quiet[Check[
    StringTake[str, n // Range // RandomChoice],
    StringTake::take
]];
f["abcde", 10]

(* POSSIBLE OUTPUTS
    "abcd"
    Cannot take positions `1` through `2` in "`3`".
*)
```

But the string template above is not filled in. I don't know what numerical value went into `2`, even though, by removing `Quiet` I can see the actual values printed in the notebook.

Obviously, in this case it is trivial to capture the random choice inside the body of `f`. But, is there a way to capture the full text of generated messages programmatically, for processing by subsequent functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`Enclose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Enclose.html) and [`ConfirmQuiet`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConfirmQuiet.html) should allow you to do this:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[str_, n_] := Enclose @ ConfirmQuiet @ StringTake[str, RandomChoice @ Range @ n];
```

it either returns a string or failure

```
res = f["abcde", 10]
```

[image]

From which you can easily retrieve the message that would have been issued:

```
In[47]:= res["HeldMessageCall"]

Out[47]= Hold[Message[StringTake::take,1,7,"abcde"]]
```

I avoid `Check` whenever possible.

Comment: But not every message generates a `Failure` object. In particular, `Molecule::aromat` does not. How do you handle those cases?

Comment: I do not reproduce that - `Enclose[ConfirmQuiet@Molecule["c1cccooc1"]]` returns a `Failure` for me (in versions 12.3 and later, I do not have earlier versions installed)

Comment: Okay, it does with `ConfirmQuiet` and `Enclose`. Without them, `Molecule["c1cccooc1"]` returns `True` for `MoleculeQ` and `False` for `FailureQ`, which is very confusing.